# How to correctly destroy spinner once it reaches certain value

Tags: jquery-ui

In my application once user has entered certain value in the spinner I should change content of the view. As part of this process I need to destroy and remove spinner.

The problem is that spinner gets into the loop and increments its' value to no end.
Sample code:

```
spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('change');
    },
    spin: function( event, ui ) { 
            console.log( 'spin event, value = ', ui.value );
        if ( ui.value == 3 ) {
            spinner.spinner( "destroy" );
        }
    }
});
```

Please check the following sample: http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/312/

Increase value 3 times: click, click, click

How can this be achieved?

Update:
Two options available here.

1. To use stop event instead of spin.
2. To trigger mouse up event before destroying spinner. With mouse up spinner will remove it handlers and destroy will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just prevent the default event!

```
spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('change');
    },
    spin: function( event, ui ) {  
        if ( ui.value == 3 ) {
            //NEW
            event.preventDefault();
            spinner.spinner( "destroy" );
       }
    }
});
```

[**old fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/XseWc/314/)

See this [documentation entry](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). It prevents the spinner from doing the normal (default) behaviour.

**EDIT**

Perhaps this can be seen as a workaround but this solution works and doesn't trigger tons of errors.

```
$(function () {
    var value;
    spinner = $("#spinner").spinner({
        change: function (event, ui) {
            console.log('change');
        },
        spin: function (event, ui) {
            value = ui.value;
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if (value == 3) {
                $(this).spinner("destroy");

            }
        }
    });
});
```

[**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XseWc/316/)

Comment: Interesting...didn't saw that at first glance. I'll check a few things

Comment: My updated answer works. No clue why the errors occur. Perhaps it's a jQuery UI bug...but not sure

Comment: stop and spin are not quite the same. For now implemented "hack" - calling mouse up on arrows before destroying spinner. That they it stops its' handlers and I remove it completely.

Comment: Yes of course...but stop is just called after spinning so it shouldn't be that dramatically different. Not sure, maybe it's worth opening a bug ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (both hide() and remove() worked for me)

```
spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('change');
    },
    spin: function( event, ui ) {  
        if ( ui.value == 3 ) {
            spinner.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Spin event is still called, not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Will this accomplish what you're looking for?

```
spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('change');
    },
    spin: function( event, ui ) {  
        if ( ui.value == 3 ) {
            spinner.remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Add `console.log` to spin event. Even after remove it is still called.